# Service layer vs business layer - differences?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, architecture, service-layer, business-logic-layer

I have been doing a lot of reading on service layers and business layers and how they compare. I have a read a number of the threads here on StackOverflow on the topic and i still find myself confused as to the differences between the two if there are any. To me it seems that its mainly a naming convention where one dev calls the middle layer a business layer and another may call it a service layer. From the code i have seen here on SO and around the web they seem to do mainly the same thing - that is query the repository, maybe do some filtering and/or validation and return the results to the presentation layer. So can anyone clarify the differences between the two? Or am i missing the mark in my assesment?

I am working with EF, MVC 3 and VBNET, FYI

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In our projects we often have the following structure:

Service layer:

- Publishes the Service Endpoint (this could be your MVC web page, or a WCF endpoint)
- Does a security check
- Maps data from contract data transfer objects to business objects
- Calls functionality in the business layer

Business layer

- Contains business logic
- Accesses the data layer (this could be your entity framework data model)

Comment: I am a bit confused: Is a webpage part of the service layer? I am guessing you mean a URL maybe?

Comment: @ShirazBhaiji  In which layer do you write validation rules?

Comment: @Shiraz Bhaiji MVC web page should be on your presentation layer not service layer.

Comment: Refer to this MSDN page to get more details about service layer and business layer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658090.aspx